# Selenium Traverse Up the DOM an unknown length in Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, dom

I've got a web page that dynamically generates content. As a result, I don't know far up the tree I need to travel, but I know the id of a target child element. I would like to travel up and find the first h1 tag above it, I simply don't know how far up I have to go to access the h1 tag, but I know it will be an xxxxParent of the tag. Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

EDIT: I am unsure just how the dom will end up until runtime. I only know that the h1 tag is some parent of the target however it could be

```
h1/table/th/label[@id=target]
```

or

```
h1/div/div/div/table/td/table/td/div/div/table/th/label[@id=target]
```

Comment: You may provide a reasonable portion of your html. It'll help to solve the issue.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know the structure of my HTML until runtime. so my dom could be anything from h1/table/th/label[@id=target] or h1/div/div/div/table/td/table/td/div/div/table/th/label[@id=target]

Answer (score 0):

Could try `(//label[@id='target']/ancestor::h1)[last()]`.

The `[last()]` is simply to select the closest ancestor (e.g. if that h1 tag also has an h1 ancestor).

These are [XPath Axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp).

Comment: This did not help me sadly.

Comment: Could you post some snippet of the code you're using to fetch this?